# Postgres set auto increment counter to a fixed value

Tags: postgresql

I want to set primary value to start with 1000 in postgres.

i know a command in mysql

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
```

how to write the above mysql command in `postgres` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identity` (and the [somewhat outdated](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) `serial`) columns are based on sequences.

You can set the sequence associated with such a column using `setval()`

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'column_name'), 1000);
```

Comment: serial is outdated? what is alternate to use?

Comment: @Curious: as I wrote: `identity` columns. See [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) for details